# Android opengl rotation using sensors data

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, augmented-reality, sensors

i try to create an Augmented Reality app with opengl view on top of the camera preview. I got camera preview and opengl view, i gather sensors data from sensors manager and then create rotation matrix to apply it to my opengl view. So far so good. I'm using only landscape phone orientation. But here is my problem:

I'm using rotation matrix from sensors, apply it to opengl and then i want to draw my models which are in constant move around (0,0,0) point. But when i rotate my phone i can of course follow my objects movement, but when i change direction (assume i rotate my phone in right direction and then change it to opposite - left. In this moment my object should move on his path, but he stays in place and move little back.

My code and screen from phone:

```
 private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];

onDrawFrame:
moveObjects(smoothedDeltaRealTime_ms);
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix, 0);
gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1f, 0f, 0f);
drawObjects(gl);

 @Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    ArOpenGlLogger.info("onSurfaceChanged " + width + "x" + height);

    this.screenWidth = width;
    this.screenHeight = height;

    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Set color's clear-value 
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f); // Set depth's clear-value to farthest
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);   // Enables depth-buffer for hidden surface removal
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);      // The type of depth testing to do

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);    // Enable smooth shading of color
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);   // Disable dithering for better performance
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);    // Enable texture
}

  protected void draw(GL10 gl) {

    //loading textures
    if(!isTextureLoaded) loadTexture(gl);

    gl.glTranslatef(translation.getX(), translation.getY(), translation.getZ());
    gl.glScalef(scale.getX(), scale.getY(), scale.getZ());

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);  
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer); 

    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

Sensors:

```
  rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedAccelerometrData, accelerometrData);
        rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedMagneticFieldData, magneticFieldData);
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, bufferedAccelerometrData, bufferedMagneticFieldData);

        if(deviceOrientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            float[] result = new float[16];
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, result);

            sensorCallback.onNewRotationMatrix(result);
        }
        else sensorCallback.onNewRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix);

  private void rootMeanSquareBuffer(float[] target, float[] values) {

      final float amplification = 200.0f;
      float buffer = 20.0f;

      target[0] += amplification;
      target[1] += amplification;
      target[2] += amplification;
      values[0] += amplification;
      values[1] += amplification;
      values[2] += amplification;

      target[0] = (float) (Math.sqrt((target[0] * target[0] * buffer + values[0] * values[0]) / (1 + buffer)));
      target[1] = (float) (Math.sqrt((target[1] * target[1] * buffer + values[1] * values[1]) / (1 + buffer)));
      target[2] = (float) (Math.sqrt((target[2] * target[2] * buffer + values[2] * values[2]) / (1 + buffer)));

      target[0] -= amplification;
      target[1] -= amplification;
      target[2] -= amplification;
      values[0] -= amplification;
      values[1] -= amplification;
      values[2] -= amplification;
}
```

Screen from device:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/JJIyohL.png]